# Uncheck the checkbox when no element is selected. check only one checkbox. change background-color of relevent div container.

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

```
<div id="grand-parent" class="grand-parent">
        <div class="parent-div">
            <p> A </p>
            <input type="checkbox"  class="select-me" name="1" value="1"/> 

         </div>   
</div>
<div id="grand-parent-1" class="grand-parent">
        <div class="parent-div">
            <p> B </p>
            <input type="checkbox"  class="select-me" name="2" value="2"/> 
    </div>

</div
    ><div id="grand-parent-2" class="grand-parent">
        <div class="parent-div">
            <p> C </p>
            <input type="checkbox"  class="select-me" name="3" value="3"/> 


        </div>   
</div>


$('.select-me').change(function(){

    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        $('.select-me').each(function(){ $(this).attr('checked', false); });
        $(this).attr('checked', true);

        $('#grand-parent').css('background','#999');
    }
    else if($(this).not(':checked')){
        $('.select-me').each(function(){ $(this).attr('checked', false); });
           $(this).attr('checked', false);
        $('.grand-parent').css('background','green');
    }
});
```

Jsfiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/2XsY5/27/

I need help to change the background-color of relevant checkbox. only one checkbox should be selected at a time. All unselected checkbox should have default background-color. only the desired checkbox should have different background-color. I appreciate for help.

Comment: `radio` elements are meant for single-choice, `checkbox` is meant for multiple. It sounds like you're wanting radio boxes... any reason you're not using them?

Comment: I understand radio elements should be used for single-choice, but I need to use checkbox.

Comment: May I know why? Limiting checkboxes to one choice is really just the same as a radio...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this, Hope this is the one you expected!

```
$(function(){
    $('.select-me').change(function(){
        $this = $(this);
        $('.select-me').each(function(){
            if($(this).val()==$this.val())
            {
              $(this).parents('.grand-parent').css('background','#999');
            }else{
                $(this).attr('checked', false);
                $(this).parents('.grand-parent').css('background','green');
            }
        });

    });
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/FvN7v/

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using `radio` elements if you want only one form element to be checked at a time.

To solve the background issue, you can just use the change event to get the input elements parent:

```
$('[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
      $('[type=checkbox]').not(this).removeAttr('checked').parents('.grand-parent').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).parents('.grand-parent').addClass('selected');
});
```

Note: Updated demo to add a class to grand parent div as requested, and remove class to all inputs not checked.

There are many ways of traversing the DOM to the elements you want, you can use `.parent().parent()` or other methods but the result is the same.

http://jsfiddle.net/2XsY5/31/

Comment: Unfortunately, the class is sitting above the parent element.

Comment: Which class? It doesn't matter which element you need, just use jQuery DOM traversal methods. You can use `parents()` etc

Comment: I need to target grand-parent class. It has been specifically asked me to use checkbox.